Signed measure integrals
I discover the signed measures.
Let $\phi: \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function such that:
For all $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$, $\phi(\cdot, \theta)$ is measurable.
For all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $\phi(x, \cdot)$ is convex and continuously differentiable.
For all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$, $\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial \theta} (x, \theta) \leq M$, where $M > 0$ is a constant.
Let $\bar{\theta} \in \mathbb{R}$. We denote by $E$ the set of finite signed measures $\nu$ on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\phi(\cdot, \bar{\theta}) \in L^1(\nu)$, i.e., such that $\phi(\cdot, \bar{\theta}) \in L^1(\nu^+)$ and $\phi(\cdot, \bar{\theta}) \in L^1(\nu^-)$, where $\nu^+$ and $\nu^-$ are the positive and negative parts of $\nu$, respectively (in particular, $\nu^+$ and $\nu^-$ are two finite positive measures, and $\nu = \nu^+ - \nu^-$).
For each $\nu \in E$, we define the function $\Phi_\nu: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ by
$\Phi_\nu(\theta) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \phi(x, \theta) d\nu(x), \quad \forall \theta \in \mathbb{R}$
We now denote by $D$ the set of probabilities $P \in E$ such that $\Phi_P$ has a unique minimizer on $\mathbb{R}$, denoted by $T(P)$.
For the rest of the discussion, let $P_0$ be a probability on $\mathbb{R}$ such that:
$P \in D$.
The function $\Phi_{P_0}$ is twice differentiable at $\theta_0 := T(P_0)$, with $\Phi_{P_0}^{\prime \prime} (\theta_0) > 0$.

Show that the definition of the space $E$ does not depend on the choice of $\bar{\theta} \in \mathbb{R}$, and that the function $\Phi_\nu$ is therefore well-defined for all $\nu \in E$.

I am not sure. Is it because in the integral $\int \phi d \nu(x)$,$\phi$ is not integrated with respect to $\theta$, but with respect to $x$ ?
For the second part of the question, can I write :
$\Phi_\nu(\theta) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \phi(x, \theta) d\nu(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \phi(x, \theta) d\nu^+(x) -  \int_{\mathbb{R}} \phi(x, \theta) d\nu^-(x)$ ?
Thanks in advance.
